Probability that a permutation of length $n$ has no cycle great than length $k$.
For example, lets say we have elements, $(012)(34)(567)(89)\in S_{10}$ and $(0123456)(789)\in S_{10}$; which are a 2x(2-cycle),2x(3-cycle) vs (7-cycle),(3-cycle). Based on this question, the probability of having a cycle of length $k$, if $k>5$, is $1/k$, so
$$P(\text{having a cycle of length k>5})=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}=64.56\%$$
So, I at least know that the probability of
$$P(\text{having no cycle greater than length 4})<35.4.4\%$$
In general, how does one find the
$$P(\text{having no cycle great than length k})$$
where $k$ is between $1$ and $n/2$.

This turns out to be a solved problem (asymptotically at least): the probability in question is approximately $\rho(N/k)$, where $\rho$ is the Dickman–de Bruijn function. You can find this statement in Section 1.4 of this paper of Granville; the entire paper is a very informative read.
